# how to set the AUTO_INCREMENT on Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

- I have a table with a Trigger that make a Auto_increment.

  ```
  CREATE TABLE Auto 
     (    Auto_id NUMBER(*,0), 
          model_id NUMBER(*,0)
     );
  ```

  --Trigger

  ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  tr_Auto_autoident 
    BEFORE INSERT ON  Auto 
    FOR EACH ROW 
     BEGIN  
       IF inserting THEN 
         IF :NEW.Auto_id IS NULL THEN 
             SELECT seq_auto__id.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.Auto_id FROM dual; 
         END IF; 
      END IF; 
  END;

    ALTER TRIGGER  tr_Auto_autoident ENABLE;
  ```
- I create the sequence too.

-- Sequence

```
   CREATE SEQUENCE seq_auto__id ;
```

I would like to set the autoident to a fix value to start , because my table had previos values before the trigger Auto_incremente were set.

Thanks , any help is apreciated.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks !! i see it , I was looking for a command but i see that the solution ist just drop and create again.

Comment: Or recreate the sequence with the [`start with` argument](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314), as the docs show.

Comment: Dropping can have side effects (dependant objects get invalidated, grants are lost...) so I prefer ALTER SEQUENCE.

Comment: Yes, I agree in general, this just looked like a new sequence/trigger being created to start auto-incrementing, so I'd build it into the initial object creation. As a separate issue, (a) the `IF :NEW.Auto_id IS NULL` means people can still insert without using the sequence, which may cause problems when the sequence reaches the manually-entered value; and (b) from 11g you can do `:NEW.Auto_id := seq_auto__id.NEXTVAL` instead of selecting from dual.